# The Jacobson Radical of a local Endomorphism ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

Let $R$ be a Henselian, local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, that is indecomposable.

It can be shown, that in this case the Endomorphism ring $End_R(M)$ is a local ring.

So let $h\in End_R(M)$. Assume that $h$ is not a isomorphism. Than $h$ is not a unit and hence lies in the maximal ideal of $End_R(M)$ which is the same as the Jacobson radical.

Why can I conclude that some power of $h$ is in $\mathfrak{m}End_R(M)$?

Comment: I couldn't immediately see why... it's a little bit of unfamiliar territory. Does $R[h]$ being a finite product of Henselian local rings help?

Comment: @rschwieb To be honest. I don't know what $R[h]$ is...

Comment: The smallest ring in $End_R(M)$ containing $R$ and $h$. It's like $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ in $\mathbb C$.  $R[h]$ would be a finite commutative ring extension of $R$, so I thought it was likely to be important.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see where this goes :/

Comment: I've been trying to think about $End_R(M)/\mathfrak{m}End_R(M)$ and how to prove $h$ is nilpotent in it... I haven't seen why... It can be viewed as a vector space over $R/\mathfrak{m}$, but I don't know if that helps...

Comment: @rschwieb any chance that $End_R(M)/\mathfrak{m}End_R(M)$ is artinian? Because then the Jacobson radical of $End_R(M)/\mathfrak{m}End_R(M)$ would be nilpotent...

Comment: Could be: what you said made me remember that since $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ has finite composition length, $End(M/\mathfrak{m} M)$ will have a nilpotent radical. Maybe this is related?